# Indentificar objetos em uma imagem com javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, processamento-de-imagens, visão-computacional

É possível identificar objetos em uma determinada imagem com Javascript ou PHP?
Reconhecimento facial eu sei que tem como, e como seria outros objetos?

Comment: Acredito que reconhecimento de objetos seja bem mais simples do que o facial, porém não sei como fazer e tenho interesse na resposta.

Comment: com javascript eu acredito que não seja possível, quanto à PHP, ja fiz um algoritimo para identificar cores em imagens e é bastante lento, logo, se houver como fazer essa identificação com PHP imagino que o desempenho será sofrível, existem outras linguagens mais capazes de processar imagens.

Comment: Acredito que a sua pergunta é ampla demais. Existem livros inteiros escritos com esta finalidade, pois trata-se de uma área bem ampla e complexa, uma vez que o reconhecimento de imagens tem vários processos tais como segmentação, filtragem, eliminação de ruído, detecção de bordas, reconhecimento de formas, avaliação de similaridade, etc. E também depende do tipo de objetos que você quer identificar e do tipo de imagens. Você poderia especificar melhor o que você está tentando fazer exatamente?

Comment: @VictorStafusa tecnicamente não é trabalho de um cara só.

Comment: A nível de curiosidade: https://www.imageidentify.com/

Answer (score -2):

Pesquise machine learning e inteligência artificial. Você e precisa de uma rede neural, precisa treinar essa rede neural pra reconhecer cada tipo de objeto, precisa de um servidor ou um cluster decente, e esquece PHP. JavaScript talvez, usando o NodeJS.